# Spring Boot Admin 2.0.1 minimum Spring Boot version

Tags: spring-boot-admin

Which is the minimum version of Spring Boot compatible with Spring Boot Admin 2.0.1?

I have a project which uses Spring Boot 1.5.8 and I would like to use Spring Boot Admin last version but it results in:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 27 more
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Spring Boot Admin 2.0.1 at least requires Spring Boot 2.0.2

Comment: It is possible. check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate spring boot admin 2.0 with 1.5.X and 2.0 . Follow these steps for spring boot 1.X

#### 1. Add this dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7</version>
</dependency>
```

#### 2. Add spring boot admin URL in application properties

```
spring.boot.admin.url: http://localhost:7777  
spring.boot.admin.api-path: instances
```

For full project check my [project](https://github.com/javatechy/spring_boot_admin)

#### References:

https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/802
http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#monitoring-spring-boot-1.5.x